# Weird issue with `fetch`

Tags: javascript, https, fetch-api

Please help, I'm getting a very weird issue with js fetch.

I'm trying to fech this from a userscript (it's public):
https://naurok.com.ua/api2/test/sessions/303532970

```js
fetch("https://naurok.com.ua/api2/test/sessions/303532970/").then(x => x.json()).then(console.log);
```

But it only works in Firefox and only if HTTPS-only mode is enabled

`fetch`ing
https://naurok.com.ua/api2/test/sessions/303532970/
makes a redirect to
http://naurok.com.ua/api2/test/sessions/303532970
(notice the lack of https and "/")
which works but serves the request over http, which gets blocked (Mixed content)

...But if the browser upgrades the redirected request to https instead of blocking (like in firefox https-only mode) it succeeds and returns the data:
`Object { session: {…}, settings: {…}, document: {…}, questions: (10) […] }`

Opening
https://naurok.com.ua/api2/test/sessions/303532970
in browser also works fine (No redirect, it loads directly!)

But requesting
https://naurok.com.ua/api2/test/sessions/303532970
with `fetch` causes it to fail, everything goes through but the API returs "false"
(Copying headers sent by browser doesn't help, code prduced by devtools Network->Request->Copy->Fetch also fails)

How are these requests different? they look (almost) the same in DevTools.

(The API I'm working with is undocumented)

Comment: not sure what you're seeing, but firefox gives a CORS error - that's the issue

Comment: I'm using it in a userscript that's injected into naurok.com.ua. So it's not a cors issue.

Comment: oh, sorry, misread your question